# when directly sum up every individual element in a string to int, what is the value represent?

Tags: c++, string

like when when s = "wendy", I got 551. What's that?

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    sum += s.at(i);
}
```

Comment: The value represents the sum of each character as an int.

Comment: What you need is a good [book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1168156).

Comment: I'm guessing it's a poor-quality additive hash algorithm. Is this a trick question?

Comment: Sounds like some kind of joke: I got SSI from sum wendy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the sum of the ascii values in the string. Each character corresponds to a numerical value usually between 32 and 127 (ignoring wide characters and Unicode stuff for now since that's complicated).

If you want more information, try looking up "Ascii".

Answer (score 2):

From an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif):

```
'w' = 119
'e' = 101
'n' = 110
'd' = 100
'y' = 121
---
551
```